# How to ensure only one value is true in DB in Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to activate only one document at one time by click of button. For this I am using a flag: "active".

```
'click .active': function (){
          var status = nodeDB.findOne({active:true});
          nodeDB.update( {$set:{'active':true}});
         //How to set the other documents as inactive
 },
```

Elements in MongoDB

```
Document1: {Keys->value,active->true}
Document2: {Keys ->value,active->false}
```

Comment: here `findOne({active:true})` and `update( {$set:{'active':1}})` why you set in update `number` instead of `Boolean`,  and which other documents to set as inactive? can you explain more?

Comment: I want to click on button and activate the corresponding document.

Comment: Say there are 100 documents and only 1 can be active on click of the button.Rest should become inactive automatically. I am at no time should two documents be active

Comment: you want to update all documents as inactive except those documents which you have click right?

Comment: yes, only one document would remain active which is selected

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the document's `_id` somehow:

```
'click .active': function (){
          var id = this._id;
          nodeDB.update({_id: id}, {$set: {active:true}});
          nodeDB.update({_id: {$ne: id}}, {$set:{'active':false}}, {multi:true});
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you need to get the id of the document you want to activate. I don't know the project and what syntax it would be like but it should be something like:

```
'click .active': function (documentId){

//Ensure you update only this document
var status = nodeDB.findAndModify({
    query: {active: true, _id: documentId},
    update: {active: true},
    upsert: false,
    new: true
});

//Update all docs other than the one you have
nodeDB.update(
    { query: {id: {$ne: status._id}} },
    { upsert: false },
    { update: {active: false} }
);
},
```