# How to use update() in meteor to insert new variable in existing document

Tags: meteor, insert-update

I want to add new variable in the existing DB Document.
I am using

```
 nodeDB.update( this._id,{$set:{'activeTemplate':1}});
```

However on the click of the submit button , the other values become null.
What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we have the whole code for your event please?

Comment: nodeDB has other elements already stored for eg: Template_Name,Template_Size, just want to update this flag which is set to 0 initially

Comment: How did you store these other elements? Using `update` on the same `_id`?

Comment: no they are already in the db, Inserted manually

Comment: Ah, well then, you have a list of documents, with each one having a different key in them: `Template_Name`, `Template_Size`, `activeTemplate`, correct? If so, it sounds normal that all the other values of your document containing `activeTemplate` are undefined.

Comment: yes Document1:[Template_Name:"A",Template_Size:35Kb,activeTemplate:0] and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set would update the entire document.
Instead we should use push in this case.

nodeDB.update( this._id,{$push:{'activeTemplate':1}});

Comment: Oh, so you wanted to add a new *value* to an *array* (named `activeTemplate`) in your *document*. You should maybe edit your question for clarity.

Comment: no activeTemplate is only a flag set to 0/1, db is nodeDB

Comment: When using `$push` this way, you are technically asking MongoDB to **append** the value `1` to the `activeTemplate` property of the document which `_id` is `this._id`. So it considers `activeTemplate` as [an array](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push).

Comment: Also can you please tell me how to set flags in other documents to 0 simultaneously, sharing link to question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046138/how-to-ensure-only-one-value-is-true-in-db-in-meteor-app